# problem with message passing in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a chrome extension and I trying to communicate between the content script and background.html page. I am storing some values(local storage) in the background.html and getting it whenever i need it in the content script. My listener listens to the request that i send from contentscript and fetches the data and sends it back to the contentscript. But when I receive it in contentscript my data becomes "undefined".

This is my code:

**background.html:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener( 
  function(request,sender,sendresponse){
    if(request.Meta == '_service'){
    /*  return _getServiceOfAddon("_service");
    }
    else if(request.Meta == 'setAddOnService'){
        _setServiceAddon("_service",request.messageContent);        
    }*/
        if(request.messageContent){
            console.log('message content for setservice : '+request.messageContent);
            _setServiceOfAddon("_service",request.messageContent);      
        }
        else{
            //return _getServiceOfAddon("_service");
            console.log('message content for getservice : '+request.messageContent);
            var temp = _getServiceOfAddon("_service");
            console.log('getting service as '+ temp);
            sendresponse({ mydata : temp });
        }
    }
  });
```

**Content Script:**

```
  Tagg.sideBar.backgroundInteraction.prototype.sendMessageToBackground = function(meta,messagecontent){
    if(!meta){
        chrome.extension.sendRequest(
            {
                Meta:'testingMessageConfirmation',
                messageContent:'This is a testing message sent from content script to background'
            },
            function(response){}
        );
    }
    else{
        chrome.extension.sendRequest(
            {
                Meta:meta,
                messageContent:messagecontent
            },
            function(response){
                //if(!response.data){
                    console.log('response data received as : '+ response.mydata);   
                    return response;
                // }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

The response.data that i receive in the contentscripts is "undefined". Can anybody point the mistake that I am making here? This seems to be very simple but I could not find the exact point where I make the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First of, what exact type of object does `_getServiceOfAddon()` return? I'm sure the intent is to return a string, but with message passing one possible cause of an `undefined` error is trying to pass things like classes, functions, etc. You might want to try `console.log` on the `response` object.

The more likely possibility is using `return`, which doesn't work great with asynchronous stuff like message passing. You should probably assign the return value to its target some other way, like using `this` or passing a reference to the DOM object or assigning it to a hash like `settings["_service"]`.

In other words, `Tagg.sideBar.backgroundInteraction.sendMessageToBackground()` will always return `undefined` as is. The callback function you have in `chrome.extension.sendRequest()` returns the `response` to `chrome.extension.sendRequest`, **not** `sendMessageToBackground()`. Remember that a function returns a value to its caller, and in this case its caller is `sendRequest()`

Comment: The function does returns a string and i am sending that response back to my content script page. Untill I send the response I get the proper value of the string [ console.log('getting service as '+ temp); ]  gives me the right string. Only when I send it back to the content script I am getting it as "undefined".

Comment: What does console.log('response data received as : '+ response.mydata); return? And how are you using the sendMessageToBackground() bit? If you're using it for assignment like `var a = Tagg...sendMessageToBackground()` it will be undefined because the return value for the function **is** undefined. The value "returned" is only returned to `chrome.extension.sendRequest`, which can't do anything with it.

Comment: the **console.log('response data received as : '+ response.mydata);** returns "undefined". And after that there is no way for me to use the value returned. There is no value returned from background.html page to the contentscript.

Comment: Is it because you're setting request.messageContent? In your example it looks like this is always true, so `sendresponse` would never be called in your background script. (If this is the case, still, keep in mind the above advice about "return response" not doing anything.)

Comment: No actually everything is perfect just before sending the data from background.html . But the moment when I receive it in the content scripts it goes undefined. Even before returning the response it is received as "undefined".

Comment: One weird thing thats happening is when I add an alert statement alerting the response.data that I receive the function in sendRequest gets called twice and the second time when it gets called I get the data from background.html page. 

All I am doing is sending a message from background.html to content script. Do anybody have any idea as to what might be the problem?